# Random outer border in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a React app and am using Material UI for most of my frontend styling, and I've found one weird little bug that I can't seem to figure out. On some of my pages I have a [random small white border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWji7.png) all the way around the edge of the page, and then on others [the border is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdE4n.png). Any ideas how I can get rid of the border on all pages?

Here's my code:

App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div style={{backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3'}}>
            <Header />
            <h1>Gas App</h1>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />

                <Route exact path="/cars" component={AllCars} />
                <Route exact path="/cars/register" component={CreateCar} />
                <Route exact path="/cars/edit/:id" component={EditCar} />
                <Route exact path="/cars/delete/:id" component={DeleteCar} />

                <Route exact path="/fillups" component={AllFillups} />
                <Route exact path="/fillups/new" component={CreateFillup} />
                <Route exact path="/fillups/edit/:id" component={EditFillup} />
                <Route exact path="/fillups/delete/:id" component={DeleteFillup} />

                <Route path="/:user" component={Profile} />
                

                <Route component={PageNotFound} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>

    )
}
```

Profile.js (has the random white border)

```
export default function Profile() {

    const location = useLocation();
    console.log('Location=' + location.pathname.split("/")[2]);

    const { user } = useParams();
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

    const [cars, setCars] = useState(null)
    const [fillups, setFillups] = useState(null)
    const { username } = useContext(Context);

    const locationToValue = (location) => {
        switch(location) {
            case 'stats':
                return 1;
            case 'fillups':
                return 2;
            case 'cars':
                return 3;
            default:
                return 0;
        }

    };

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = useState(locationToValue(location.pathname.split("/")[2]));

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Promise.all([
        //     axiosInstance.get('/fillups/?user__user_name=' + user),
        //     axiosInstance.get('/cars/?user__user_name=' + user)
        // ]).then(function ([res1, res2]) {
        //     setFillups(res1.data)
        //     setCars(res2.data);
        // });
        console.log('Value=' + value);
        console.log('Path=' + path);
        console.log('URL=' + url);
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>{user}'s Profile</h1>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example" variant="fullWidth">
                        <Tab label="Overview" component={Link} to={`${url}`} {...a11yProps(0)} />
                        <Tab label="Stats" component={Link} to={`${url}/stats`} {...a11yProps(1)} />
                        <Tab label="Fillups" component={Link} to={`${url}/fillups`} {...a11yProps(2)} />
                        <Tab label="Cars" component={Link} to={`${url}/cars`} {...a11yProps(3)} />
                    </Tabs>
                </AppBar>

                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={`${path}`}>
                        <ProfileOverview user={user} />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path={`${path}/stats`}>
                        <ProfileStats user={user} />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path={`${path}/fillups`}>
                        <ProfileFillups user={user} />
                    </Route>

                    <Route exact path={`${path}/cars`}>
                        <ProfileCars user={user} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

and CreateCar.js (no white border)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function CreateCar() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Register New Car
                </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="car_name"
                                label="Car Name"
                                name="car_name"
                                autoComplete="car_name"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="make"
                                label="Make"
                                name="make"
                                autoComplete="make"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <TextField
                                variant="outlined"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="model"
                                label="Model"
                                name="model"
                                autoComplete="model"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                                <InputLabel>Model Year</InputLabel>
                                <Select
                                    required
                                    onChange={handleSelectChange}
                                    id="model_year"
                                    label="Model Year"
                                    name="model_year"
                                    autoComplete="model_year"
                                    value={formData.model_year}
                                >
                                    {
                                    model_year_range.map((year) => (
                                        <MenuItem value={year}>{year}</MenuItem>
                                    ))
                                    }
                                </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                            <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                                <InputLabel>Status</InputLabel>
                                <Select
                                    required
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    id="status"
                                    label="status"
                                    name="status"
                                    autoComplete="status"
                                    value={formData.status}
                                >
                                    <MenuItem value="Active">Active</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value="Inactive">Inactive</MenuItem>
                                </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                        onClick={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Register Car
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Best guess, `classes.root` has some styling that includes a border, but since you haven't provided that styling, it's impossible to say for sure. That said, there is *a lot* of irrelevant code here. If you can reduce your question to [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. in this case, boil your code down to something like a styled box, it's not only much easier to provide help, but likely that in doing so, you may discover the problem on your own. Try getting some basic examples up e.g. on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

Comment: I should have trimmed down my code, you're right. I actually didn't include the classes.root styling because I had already tested removing that styling entirely and it didn't have an effect. When trimming down for a more minimal example I actually figured out my issue. In my page without the border, I had included the CssBaseline from Material-UI. I'm a little too new to have a full understanding on why specifically that fixes it, but my problem is solved

Comment: The basic idea is that all browsers have CSS defaults, and they are not necessarily the same or may reflect a time when something made sense but no longer does (and can't be changed, because someone out there is relying on it). You can look at the [CSS Baseline docs](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/#page) for more. Notice how it says e.g. "The margin in all browsers is removed," which sounds like it could be what you were seeing. Trying opening up dev tools in your browser (F12) and selecting the border (Ctrl-C) to see what it is (margin, padding?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my issue while trimming my code for an easier to read question. In the component that did not have the issue, I had the whole component wrapped in a container, with the cssbaseline MUI component included, while the component that had the border did not. So the return statement of my Profile component is now as follows:

```
return (
        <Container component="main">
            <CssBaseline />
            <h1>{user}'s Profile</h1>
            <div>
                {other component stuff here}
            </div>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the bootstrap class `container` and I got padding around because of that